# Carrying HTML text fields values to Batch File variables

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file

I am looking to have a HTML form which has three input boxes for Customer.ID, First Name and Last Name which will carry the values input by the user in these boxes into a batch file as variables. I am then looking for the batch value to echo the values input individually.

```
<!-- :
:: textSubmitter.bat
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~f0"') do (
    set "CustomerID=%%a"
    set "FirstName"=%%b"
    set "LastName"=%%c"
)

echo Your Customer ID is %CustomerID%
echo Your First Name is %FirstName%
echo Your Last Name is %LastName%
pause

-->

<html>
  <head>
    <title>COI Request</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script language='javascript' >
        function pipeText() {
            var CustomerID=document.getElementById('CustomerID').value;
            var Cust1= new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
            close(Cust1.Write(CustomerID));

            var FirstName=document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
            var Frst1= new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
            close(Frst1.Write(FirstName));

            var LastName=document.getElementById('LastName').value;
            var Lst1= new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);            
            close(Lst1.Write(LastName));
      }
    </script>

    <input type='text' name='CustomerID' size='25'></input><br>
    <input type='text' name='FirstName' size='25'></input><br>
    <input type='text' name='LastName' size='25'></input><br>
    <hr>
    <button onclick='pipeText()'>Submit</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Looking to have the 3 values which are input into the HTML form carried over to the Batch file as variable values shown in the code attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code have several small errors. This works:

```
<!-- :
:: textSubmitter.bat
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~f0"') do (
    set "CustomerID=%%a"
    set "FirstName=%%b"
    set "LastName=%%c"
)

echo Your Customer ID is %CustomerID%
echo Your First Name is %FirstName%
echo Your Last Name is %LastName%
pause
goto :EOF

-->

<html>
  <head>
    <title>COI Request</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script language='javascript' >
        function pipeText() {
            var CustomerID=document.getElementById('CustomerID').value;
            var FirstName=document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
            var LastName=document.getElementById('LastName').value;

            var Batch = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
            close(Batch.WriteLine(CustomerID+','+FirstName+','+LastName));
      }
    </script>

    <input type='text' name='CustomerID' size='25'></input><br>
    <input type='text' name='FirstName' size='25'></input><br>
    <input type='text' name='LastName' size='25'></input><br>
    <hr>
    <button onclick='pipeText()'>Submit</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Aacini, this worked and helped me big time moving forward with what I am doing. Still new to this area so it's rookie errors i couldn't see myself. Thanks for your help, it's greatly appreciated!